# Send Message to Background Window

Tags: c#, outlook, sendmessage

Basically, what I'd like to do is to send keystrokes to a background, inactive window.
In my case, outlook. I want to create a mail spammer, (in school thing), but I can only do it while it is in the foreground, which prevent's the user doing anything while this is happening, e.g if they want to send around 1000 messages.

If you really want to know, I am the only person in my grade who knows how to code past a simple `MessageBox.Show()`. And, there are these people who think they are 'cool' when they spam people (no anti-spam on our outlooks)with messages doing the `CTRL R + ENTER` keystrokes. I've made a program that does it, spams around 10 emails a second, but I can't use my computer when it's doing it.

I've done some research and I've found that the `SendMessage()` thing should work, but will it and can it work on background processes?
Any code I could use?

Answer (score 2):

Why exactly are you sending keystrokes instead of using the Outlook Object Model?
The whole square pig in a round hole thing might work sometimes, but why do you want to be a glutton for punishment?

Start at http://www.outlookcode.com/

Comment: It isn't exactly that, it isn't made for for exact punishment, but my friends buy programs like that off me for like $2. I take it as a learning curve as well, it would be useful for the future I guess.